# Call a server side function from javascript in asp.net 2.0 without using script manager or pagemethods

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, pagemethods

I want to update DB when the user closes the browser. I am capturing it in windows.onbeforeunload in javascript . I want to call a function in server side when the when the on before unload event and update the DB.

I am using asp.net 2.0 Framework and don't have ajax installed in my system. So I scriptmanager is not recognized by asp.

Can I have any other way to call a server side function from javascript without using script manager or pagemethods. Please help!!!!

Comment: I installed ajax 1.0 on the system but what is happening is onunload function is working in master page but i cant use page method from there and onunload fucntion is not working in the content pages.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code is asp.net client side :

```
      <script>
            function CallServerMethod() {
                alert("<%= GetValue("  karthick  ") %>");
            }
     </script>
```

then write code on asp.net button as `OnClientClick="CallServerMethod();"`
i.e

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="CallServerMethod();" Text="Button" />
```

In code behind . i.e .cs page declare the function `GetValue()` as below

```
        public String GetValue(string myval)
        {
            return myval;
        }
```

as soon as you click then GetValue() you will see alert box.

Comment: hay shakir can you please help me to do so.?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could try using the [jQuery post method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).
You could even post to a different page and pass any arguments you need to do the DB update.

Comment: I have installed ajax 2.0 but i am not able to get script manager tag working. its giving error